# Get Higher Level Object from Object Array Item

Tags: php, class, object, abstract-class

I have 2 class which both extend an abstracted class. Both classes has a private method called "content" which is an array of items of the other class.
Once I add an object B into the "content" array of class A I need to get the parent object A from the item object B.
Here is the example, it's easier to look at it:

```html
<?php 

abstract class heroes {
    private $tag;
    private $content = array();
    
    function __construct($tag) {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
    
    public function getContents() {
        return $this->content;
    }
    
    protected function addContent($obj) {
        $this->content[] = $obj;
        return $obj;
    }

}

final class batman extends heroes {

    public function addPartner() {
        return $this->addContent(new robin());
    }
}

final class robin extends heroes {

    private $capes;
    
    public function dieAtFirstFight() {
        return BATMAN OBJ???
    }
    
}

$batman = new batman();
$batman = $batman->addPartner()->dieAtFirstFight();

?>
```

I tried in the abstract class to add a private method called $father in which everytime I add a partner I set $self (which is Batman object) but in the php error log I get the error "Object of class Batman could not be converted to string"

Comment: How about adding a "partner" field to heros after all it is common to all heros no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to use "$this" to add the father. There is not $self in php.

```html
<?php 

abstract class heroes {
    private $tag;
    private $content = array();
    protected $father;
    
    function __construct($tag) {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
    
    public function getContents() {
        return $this->content;
    }
    
    protected function addContent($obj) {
        $this->content[] = $obj;
        $obj->setFather($this);
        return $obj;
    }
    
    protected function setFather($father) {
        $this->father = $father;
    }

}

final class batman extends heroes {

    public function addPartner() {
        return $this->addContent(new robin('tag'));
    }
}

final class robin extends heroes {

    private $capes;
    
    public function dieAtFirstFight() {
        return $this->father;
    }
    
}

$batman = new batman('tag');
$batman = $batman->addPartner()->dieAtFirstFight();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Meffen, I did an error in my answer, actually I used $this instead of $self but the error wasn't that but the "protected" in $father declaration. If the father was private generated the error, with protected everything went fine. Do you know why?